# Editor badges and edits

Tags: discussion, badges

I was going over the badges page, the two badges Copy Editor and Strunk & White (gold and silver resp.) are not very common, however when looking at the users page you can show number of edits and many users have gone far far beyond the threshold needed for either of the badges.

Furthermore, in the data.SE there are several queries to "measure how far a user is from editor badges", entering my user all say that I have gone beyond the needed edits for Strunk & White, and about 70% or so to the Copy Editor (and this is relative to two weeks ago).

So what is the deal with the edits on the Users page, and how these badges are measured?

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:**  It seems there are some strange things going on in Asaf's case, and I don't understand why he doesn't have the badge.  What follows is general information regarding what does and does not count for the editor badges, and also where to look up the information.

Only certain posts count for the editor badges. I searched around on meta.stack a little bit, and here are the relevant posts:

[What kind of edits contribute to the editor badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)  Jeff Atwood provides an answer on this page.

Also, on the page [list of all badges with full description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) we have:

**Copy Editor**

- gold; awarded once; same family as Strunk & White (silver)
- Related to Editor (bronze)
- Perform a total of 500 edits between questions, answers and tag wikis

  - Edits on deleted posts do not count
  - Edits to your own posts do not count
  - Edits to CW posts do count
  - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
  - Tag wiki edits do count
  - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do count, once approved

**Strunk & White**

- silver; awarded once; same family as Copy Editor (gold)
- Related to Editor (bronze)
- Perform a total of 80 edits between questions and answers

  - Edits on deleted posts do not count
  - Edits to your own posts do not count
  - Edits to CW posts do count
  - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
  - Tag wiki edits do count
  - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do count, once approved

**Lastly:** This is probably the most relevant part.  I searched your user ID (which is $622$ by the way) on the math stack exchange [stats page](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/q/5117/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white).  It says you need only $3$ more edits for Strunk and White.

Most likely the extra edits you have are one which do not contribute, such as tag edits or edits to your own and deleted posts.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I assume that is indeed the case. How can I know how many posts have I edited? Why do the SQL queries suggest I have enough while evidence in the Badge department say otherwise?

Comment: @Eric: Note that the data dumps are from almost two weeks ago. I can be somewhat certain that I have made those three edits.

Comment: @Asaf:  Hmmmm, I don't really know then.  Perhaps the system is just lagging, and takes time to update this badge?  Maybe Jeff can post a more helpful answer.

Comment: It looks to me that the stats page is incorrect. The necessary number of edits for the Strunk and White badge is **80** (it used to be 100). So Asaf should have gotten his badge a long time ago.

Comment: @Zev:  I was thinking the same thing.  For myself, it says I need 72 edits, considering the page says I have 60 I would hope that I have 28 legitimate edits so far.  (Rather than 8!)  There must be a bug on that page regarding the number of edits being 100 rather then 80.  Having said that, it seems the badge is awarded for 80 edits since Raeder has a total of 94 edits, yet has the Strunk and White badge.  What is going on here?  Why doesn't Asaf have the badge?

Comment: @Zev, Eric: note that since Jun 6th I have edited at least three *bodies* of questions, and a couple more titles. So if I have had 97 back then, I surely have 100 now. Worst case scenario I should be getting the badge today. Otherwise something smells bad, and I'm not talking about the rotting corpse of Punk music which lies at the corner of the room with a note "Punk not dead!".

Comment: [This other editor badge stats page](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1397/how-many-copy-editor-strunk-white-qualifying-edits-have-i-made) says that Asaf has 70 qualifying edits, but I can't tell whether it's applying all the rules as described in Eric's post (I don't know how to read the code).

Comment: You can only gain $1000$ reputation from making edits, but this is enough to get Copy Editor, and the amount of rep gained from edits is shown on math.stackexchange.com/reputation