# Badge for editing 80 posts is not functioning?

Tags: support, badges

I think the badge Strunk and White for editing 80 posts doesn't upgrade my editing posts anymore while I'm at 78/80. I've edited yesterday 5 posts after I've reached the 78 posts and today I did 2 more and nothing happened?

I already refreshed the page multiple times and logged out and then logged in and still no badge.

Do you know what it's wrong?

Comment: I'll add to mixedmath's answer that some details about this badge can also be found in [Editor badges and edits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2397) and [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397). (The latter is also linked in the [tag-info for badges](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/badges/info).)

Comment: Since tag-only edits don't count toward editing badges, I wonder whether there should be a badge specifically for tag-only edits. (Note that I'm not talking about tag-wiki edits)

Comment: Since you posted on meta, I'd like to recommend that you be more selective in proposing edits.  Some of your edits are adding collateral tags and making changes to wording where an OP used language that is just as clear and grammatically correct as your proposed wording.  There is a sufficient supply of posts that lack math formatting and/or have misspellings that you can afford to be more selective.

Comment: I'll take that into account when I make an edit. You made a good point there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've looked at your recent edits, and it appears that many are tag-only edits. Tag-only edits don't count.

For a related question (that also contains the details of how to check your count, and a description of exactly what does and doesn't count), see [Why Haven't I Received the Strunk and White Badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266137/why-havent-i-received-the-strunk-white-badge).

Comment: Oh, oké. I appreciate the detailed answer.